# Cannot instantiate UIView from nib. "warning: could not load any Objective-C class information"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, nib

I get "could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available." warning in the console while initializing an instance of this class:

```
@IBDesignable
class SystemMessage: UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_message: UILabel!

    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }


    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView{
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SystemMessage", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view 
    }


}
```

Execution stops on line `let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner...` with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2...)"

What could be the possible reason behind this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution. It all comes to understanding of how xibs work.

What I did was that I set class for both view and File's Owner and connected all the outlets from the View rather than from the File's owner.

Comment: Without XIB n Storyboard? must be very hefty.

Comment: @Dominooch The solution was to set a specific class for class owner only in a xib file. And leave its view by default.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you are going the long way round instantiating a view. You have a view of class `SystemMessage` which instantiates a nib of name `SystemMessage` and then inserts that as a view :/

The simplest way to do this is to set the root view in your Xib to be of type `SystemMessage`

[image]

Then you connect your outlets to the view that you just gave the right type

[image]

This means that you can lose have your code and end up with

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SystemMessage: UIView {

  @IBOutlet weak var lbl_message: UILabel!

  static func loadViewFromNib() -> SystemMessage {
    return NSBundle(forClass: self).loadNibNamed("SystemMessage", owner: nil, options: nil).first as! SystemMessage
  }

}
```

This just gives you an easy way to instantiate your view from code with `SystemMessage.loadViewFromNib()`. `File's Owner` is probably being set incorrectly in this instance

Comment: Yeah, I understood that I had to parse the result to SystemMessage. But, actually, it worked for me perfectly well the other way when I left the view in .xib as UIView and dragged all the outlets to "File's Owner".

Comment: Sure it will work but it's not the correct way. Technically it sounds like if you go the route you are going when you instantiate your `SystemMessage` it will create another `SystemMessage` from a nib and add it to itself. So you'll have this weird `SystemMessage` class that contains a `SystemMessage` which makes no sense

Comment: No, actually it does since it loads the UIView and adds it as a `view` property inside of a SystemMessage class instance, which, itself, acts differently depending on how its called(I didn't involve the whole implementation therefore I understand your confusion).

Comment: Oh, now I get it - SystemMessage itself is a UIView. Ok, thanks