# UIScrollView with ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swipe

I'm trying to add three UIViewControllers in a UIScrollView. If I have only two, it works perfect. When I add the third one, an error appears and the app crashes. Can anyone help me out? Here is my code:

Two ViewControllers (Works perfectly):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];



BViewController *bViewController = [[BViewController alloc]init];
CViewController *cViewController = [[CViewController alloc]init];


CGRect frame = cViewController.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 320;
cViewController.view.frame = frame;



[self addChildViewController:bViewController];
[self addChildViewController:cViewController];


[self.scrollView addSubview:bViewController.view];
[self.scrollView addSubview:cViewController.view];


[bViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[cViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;}
```

Three ViewControllers (Doesn't work):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];



AViewController *aViewController = [[AViewController alloc]init];
BViewController *bViewController = [[BViewController alloc]init];
CViewController *cViewController = [[CViewController alloc]init];


CGRect frame = cViewController.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 320;
cViewController.view.frame = frame;

CGRect frametwo = aViewController.view.frame;
frametwo.origin.x = 320 * 2;
aViewController.view.frame = frametwo;



[self addChildViewController:aViewController];
[self addChildViewController:bViewController];
[self addChildViewController:cViewController];


[self.scrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];
[self.scrollView addSubview:bViewController.view];
[self.scrollView addSubview:cViewController.view];

[aViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[bViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[cViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];



self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * 3, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;}
```

ERROR: [Here is an image of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wabh7.png)
If you cannot see the image, the error is: "Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: Check IBOutlet connection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581479/cannot-instantiate-uiview-from-nib-warning-could-not-load-any-objective-c-cla

Comment: Are you going to use xib?

Comment: Yes, I'm using xib files @SurajSukale

Comment: @kb920 Thanks for your comment but I'm new to programming and I really didn't understand the answer in that question... Can you help me out directly here please? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Try to connect all the outlets from the View instead File's owner.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have stack overflow due to recursion. Check whether your child view controllers (AViewController) try to access `ViewController` from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I'm new to programming, I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what you want me to do here. Thank you for your help! Can you be a little bit more specific? Or guide me a little bit more in what I need to do to fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: You should look for a call to your ViewController class from AViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly, Try this

```
AViewController *aViewController = [AViewController new];
BViewController *bViewController = [BViewController new];
CViewController *cViewController = [CViewController new];

CGRect aFrame = aViewController.view.frame;
CGRect bFrame = bViewController.view.frame;
CGRect cFrame = cViewController.view.frame;

//Setting the frame
aViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.origin.x, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y, aFrame.size.width, aFrame.size.height);

bViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.origin.x+aFrame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y, bFrame.size.width, bFrame.size.height);

cViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(bFrame.size.width+bFrame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y, cFrame.size.width, cFrame.size.height);

aViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
bViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
cViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

[self.scrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];
[self.scrollView addSubview:bViewController.view];
[self.scrollView addSubview:cViewController.view];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(aFrame.size.width+ bFrame.size.width+ cFrame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```