# Move text to next textfiled in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have one `UITableView` and have multiple  `UITableViewCell`.

Each cell have one `UITextFiled`.

Now I'am adding text to 1'st row textfiled. Now I want to move text to 2'nd row textfiled when that text range reaches to screen width.

**Edit :**

**Textfiled delegate method**

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    CGFloat textWidth = [textField.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textField.font}].width;
    CGFloat frameWidth = textField.frame.size.width - 11;

    if(textWidth > frameWidth) {

       //text reaches to screen width.
       [textField resignFirstResponder];

       MemoTableViewCell *nextCell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(textField.tag+1) inSection:0]];
       [nextCell.noteTextField becomeFirstResponder];

      return NO;
  }

return YES;

}
```

**Tableview methods:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    MemoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[MemoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.noteTextField.delegate = self;
    cell.noteTextField.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

Now I want to move text when above method return NO.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand my question and if not then ask me.

Help me please.

**Edit**

Above code works fine but some time it will crash on below line

```
CGFloat textWidth = [textField.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textField.font}].width;
```

> **Warning:** could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to move text"? Do you want to make the next `textField` the first responder or you want to move the text from the current `textField` to the next one?

Comment: @Adeel I want next cell textfiled becomFirstResponder when its text reaches to screen width.

Comment: check your textfield delegate connection. Where you have set it ? in Fileowner or View ? I doubt you may have connect it to View

Comment: @Wolverine Yes I have connected it to view.

Comment: Delegate must have to be connected to Controller's file owner. if you have take an .xib for cell, then try to set their delegate programatically in cellforRow and if not then set them to File owner of controller which  you can see in storyboard.

Comment: @Wolverine Yes I set it to the viewController only.

Comment: @Wolverine Weird behavior I am getting in delegate method. Please help me.

Comment: please post some more code and screenshot of tableview which contain these cells for more clear idea and check for the weird behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126289/discussion-between-ekta-padaliya-and-wolverine).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the high-level logic which you can apply to achieve your requirements.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   CGSize size = [textField.text sizeWithAttributes:
@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textField.font]}];

   if (size.width > textField.frame.size.width) {

      //text reaches to screen width.
      [textfield resignFirstResponder];

       /*
          //Get next TextField and Make it first responder
          [cell.myTextField becomeFirstResponder]; 
       */
       /*
        Add code logic here
        1. Get the next cell instance - using cellForRowAtIndexPath
        2. Get its textfield instance - cell.myTextField
        3. Make that one as first responder - [cell.myTextField becomeFirstResponder]; 
        */
       return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```

This will set the next cell's textfield as primary input and it will jump your cell to that limit.

You might require to set view position accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your valuable answer. I will try and let you know.

Comment: That textfiled delegate method is working till 25 characters only. I want to add text as screen width. Are you getting my question?

Comment: Its working fine but getting this warning **could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.**

Comment: @EktaPadaliya  Updated answer - here you need to measure the font-text width matches the textfield's width and accordingly go further.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya : Check now.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, may be it will help:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


CGFloat textWidth = [textfield.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textfield.font}].width;
CGFloat frameWidth = textfield.frame.size.width;

    if(textWidth > frameWidth) {

       //text reaches to screen width.
       [textfield resignFirstResponder];

        /*
        //Get next TextField and Make it first responder
        [cell.YourNextTextField becomeFirstResponder]; 
        */

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thnaks I will try and let you know.

Comment: sure, let me know if you have any issue@EktaPadaliya

Comment: Its working fine but getting this warning **could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.**

Comment: I think that not related to above code, try to search for it or post new question@EktaPadaliya

Comment: mark it as answer if it helped to solve your issue, so it will help other@EktaPadaliya

Comment: Check this link for that:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581479/cannot-instantiate-uiview-from-nib-warning-could-not-load-any-objective-c-cla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581479/cannot-instantiate-uiview-from-nib-warning-could-not-load-any-objective-c-cla)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `tableView` has only one section. Replace the code in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` with this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

BOOL shouldChange = YES;

NSString *text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];

CGFloat textWidth = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: textField.font}].width;

CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

if (textWidth > screenWidth) {

    shouldChange = NO;

    NSInteger cellIndex = textField.tag;

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];

    if (cellIndex < numberOfRows - 1) {

        NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellIndex+1 inSection:0];

        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];

        [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

return shouldChange;
}
```

And don't forget to set the tag of your `textField` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i.e. `cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row`.

Comment: Same issue **could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.** I am getting this warning.

Comment: on which line do you get this warning?

Comment: CGFloat textWidth = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: textField.font}].width;

Comment: Is the code working as you expect it to because I'm not getting any kind of warning and the code is also working fine. And did you try cleaning your project or restarting the Xcode?